# wp_head hook by page ID

Tags: conditional-tags, wp-head

I need help with this

```
/* meta description to head */
add_action( 'wp_head','carlos_head_meta_page' );  
function carlos_head_meta_page() { ?> 
    <meta name="description" content="vale here" />
<?php }
```

It works fine, but I would like to use a conditional tag like

```
if ( is_page('4') )
```

So I can use different meta tags for specific pages.

Comment: So use the tag then, what’s the problem?

Comment: I need to know the correct syntax as when I use it it won't work.

Comment: Can you at least post the code that doesn't work.

Comment: if ( is_page('4') )
add_action( 'wp_head','carlos_head_meta_page' );

function carlos_head_meta_page() { ?> 
    <meta name="description" content="vale here" />
<?php }

Comment: you need to put the conditional inside the function as the page query is not populated until later so is_page will not work outside of it. ie. add_action( 'wp_head','carlos_head_meta_page' ); function carlos_head_meta_page() { if (is_page('4')) { ?> <meta name="description" content="vale here" /> <?php } }

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use different meta tags for different pages I recommend you to use custom field values.

If you prefer to do it with conditional functions, try this:

```
add_action( 'wp_head','carlos_head_meta_page' );  
function carlos_head_meta_page() { 

    if ( is_page('4') ) {
        $description = 'tag1';
    } else {
        $description = 'tag2';
    }
    ?> 
    <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $description ?>" />
    <?php

}
```